# How can I keep dialogue attached to character names in a Pages play script?

Tags: software, tools, playwriting

I'm formatting a play using Pages on macOS. I cannot figure out how to get character names to be associated with their dialogue. I'm formatting like

> [centered] JOHN [\centered]
>   Yes, that’s me.

But I constantly get orphaned character names because the newline after the character name causes the two things to be treated as separate paragraphs. It looks super unprofessional.

I'm using Pages specifically, but also could switch to Word if this is impossible in Pages but possible in Word.

Comment: My guess is Word is not what you want. Have you looked for screenwriter programs that you might use? https://www.scriptreaderpro.com/free-screenwriting-software/

Comment: I’ve looked at those a little, but it’s not a screenplay, so i don’t want or need the strict screenplay format. And because play workshopping involves editing the play so frequently, I don’t want to use non-standard file formats/editing software.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I could do this in Word very easily --  Short Version: Create a **Style** called "Character Name"  Indicate that the style "Dialogue" is what follows next.  (that's on the first area of the create-a-style dialogue).  Then in the PARAGRAPHS section of that Character Name Style, the second/advanced tab, choose "**Keep-with-next**"

I do most of my editing in drafts-view, because it's easy to see in the left pane which template is being used, and to remember to make changes via Style, not direct-formatting.

---

Screenshots!
A sequence of  11 pictures.

**Drafts View, "no" styles**
1) I copied some lyrics to be my "script". I chose View, Draft, to create that left-view.  Shift-F1 is another great tool for knowing layout.
[image: This is my starting with a text snippet all in normal mode]

**Create A Style**
2) I manually centered one line, then selected it as my "model" - then on the Styles Menu, I chose Create-A-Style to get started
[image: Image shows using context-menu to start editing a Style]

**Name the Style & Start to Modify**
3)You can give any style any name.  You can also change more properties within this.
[image: Closeup of Create-Style, directing users to click "modify"]

**Styles That Can Be Buddies**
4)Most of the time, after a Character Name, there's dialog - so I previously made that style (Normal, but indented .5" on L & R, smaller space before/after paragraphs.)  So you can select a "Next Style" button as shown here, and then use the Modify button at the bottom, to see various other elements to change.
[image: Close up of Style Edit page, highlighting "Style for Following Paragraph" and "Modify" buttons]

**Modify Options**
5) In the Modify box, you can go to many areas - you may want to add a Shortcut Key so you can turn on Character Name formatting at the start of said line!  We want to do *paragraph* options now
[image: closeup of Modify drop-down menu]

**Paragraph Options, 2nd Tab**
6) The big feature you want is *"Keep with Next"*  (You may want to also have Scene Breaks start a new page - use "Page Break Before" then.)
[image: Paragraph Tab, 2nd tab, highlighting Keep With Next]

**Style Gallery**
7) Hey, there are our Styles in the gallery!
[image: Styles Gallery closeup - "Character name" is first style]

**Ta-da!**
8) Screenshot of the script, now with those character and dialog Styles added. Note there's a page break here -- I played with adding blocks of text - the character-name stayed with the dialog!  (But Things seem a little unbalanced, hmmmm...)

[image: Drafts View, showing Styles added over a page break]

**Modify Style Even More**
9) So let's fix that spacing issue -- too little space between blocks and the *next* character name. *(It's nice to know that once a style exists, it can still be modified as needed)* 
[image: Modify Style from Style Gallery]

**Back to Style Paragraphs**
10) Just the front part, playing with spacing instead of adding unneeded "enter"s to add spaces
[image: Modify Style -- Paragraph Properties]

**Really Done**
[image: Final view of script in draft-view with modified styles]

If most of what you write are plays, then you can add these Styles to your Normal.dotm template -- if not, save a template (File, Save-As, choose "file-type as .dotx or .dotm, then name it) for all playwriting styles.

---

(Note - my font styles are Arial since that's work normal -- feel free to change.  And the source of my "dialogue" is a song going through my head from *Heathers* the Musical:
(lyrics from https://genius.com/Laurence-okeefe-and-kevin-murphy-dead-girl-walking-lyrics and  https://genius.com/Laurence-okeefe-and-kevin-murphy-dead-girl-walking-reprise-lyrics )